# import json library moshi causes build failure

Tags: java, json, moshi

I want to use moshi to parse json file, this is my code:

```
import com.squareup.moshi.JsonAdapter;
import com.squareup.moshi.Moshi;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;

public class Config {

static class ConfigMessageUnit {
    int word;
    String title;
}
static class ConfigDevice {
    String type;
    int position;
    List<ConfigMessageUnit> send;
    int recvCmd;
}
static class ConfigFile {
    String db;
    String log;
    String journal;
    List<ConfigDevice> devices;
}

static public Config instance = new Config();
static ConfigFile configFile;

private Config() {
    Moshi moshi = new Moshi.Builder().build();
    JsonAdapter<ConfigFile> adapter = moshi.adapter(ConfigFile.class);
    try {
        String json = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("plcsim2.config.json"), "UTF-8");
        configFile = adapter.fromJson(json);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        configFile = null;
    }
}
```

This matches the json file. But Intellij Idea prompt me I should add moshi in module-info.java, so I applied  the suggestion. And I see a line is added to that file and now the content is:

```
module com.plcsim2j.plcsim2j {
requires javafx.controls;
requires javafx.fxml;
requires org.apache.commons.io;
requires moshi;

opens com.plcsim2j.plcsim2j to javafx.fxml;
exports com.plcsim2j.plcsim2j;
}
```

and of course I already added moshi to my build.gradle:

```
implementation("com.squareup.okio:okio:3.1.0")
implementation("com.squareup.moshi:moshi:1.13.0")
```

And now it doesn't compile! Gradle compile task failed with :

Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:/softwares/jdk-17.0.3.1-full/bin/java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

If I remove "requires moshi", and remove my "Config.java" file to make sure moshi is not used, then it compiles and application runs.

If I remove module-info.java file itself, then it works and config json is loaded correctly. But the "distZip" task fails to generate runnable zip package -- required packages not included.

So what should I do with moshi in module-info.java?